# How to prove that there is a $\xi$ such that $\frac{f(\xi)}{g(\xi)} = \frac{f''(\xi)}{g''(\xi)}$?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f(x), g(x)$ are twice differentiable over $[a,b]$ and $f(a)=f(b)=g(a)=g(b)=0$.  How to prove that there is a $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that $\frac{f(\xi)}{g(\xi)} = \frac{f''(\xi)}{g''(\xi)}$? I tried to use Lagrange mean value theorem to prove it but not successful. Thank you very much.

Edit: we also assume that $g(x), g''(x) \neq 0$ for every $x \in (a,b)$.

Comment: the result obviously fails for functions $f(x) = 0 = g(x)$ for all $x$. Hence we need some extra constraints on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: let $$F(x)=f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)$$
so
$$F''(x)=f''(x)g(x)+f'(x)g'(x)-f'(x)g'(x)-f(x)g''(x)=f''(x)g(x)-f(x)g''(x)$$
and $$F(a)=F(b)=0$$
then Use Roll therom.By Done.